# Storing floats as small integers

Tags: database, resources, storage

I am working on a project in which we collect a lot of data from many sensors. These sensors, in many cases, return low precision floats represented with 1 and 2 byte integers. These integers are mapped back to floats via some simple relation; for instance,

```
x_{float} = (x_{int} + 5) / 3
```

Each sensor will return around 70+ variables of this kind.

Currently, we expect to store a minimum of 10+ millions of entries per day, possibly even 100+ million entries per day. However, we only require like 2 or 3 of these variables on a daily basis and the others one will rarely be used (we require them for modeling purposes).

So, in order to save some space I was considering storing these small precision integers directly into the DB instead of the float value (with the exception of the 2-3 variables we read regularly, which will be stored as floats to avoid the constant overhead of mapping them back from ints). In theory, this should reduce the size of the database by almost a half.

My questions is if this is a good idea?. Will this backfire when we have to map back all the data to train models?.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. We are using Cassandra, I don't know it this may be relevant for the question.

Comment: I'm no expert, but if the goal is saving space, this sounds totally fine. Just make sure to document very well and clearly the formula for conversion haha.. would be awkward if that knowledge got forgotten.

Backfire I don't know, but of course it will take some time to convert all of that data if it's so big, both to write the script to do it and the conversion itself. And if you have to then use all the data at the same time you will need that space anyway. I've never worked with this much data though let it be known.